# Using triggers / routines with table prefixes in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm used to use mysql table prefixes in my php scripts. Yet triggers and routines sometimes are very useful too. Ok. Let's say i have a table: 'pre_customers'. And a procedure sth like

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_all_clients`() RETURNS int(11)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE sum INT ;
    SELECT COUNT(id) INTO sum FROM pre_customers ;
    RETURN sum;
END
```

No big deal, just for example. And there is also a constant

```
<?php
define( 'DB_PREFIX', 'pre_' ) ;
```

It's being used for changing table prefixes. If i need to make an sql-request in the script i make it like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customers" ;
$result = mysql_query( $query ) ;
...
```

Alright, but if i want to change this prefix in the php-script along with the table names it's gonna ruin all stored routines and triggers, they still will apply to 'pre_customers' table. So the question is is there a common practice how normally programmers solve this problem.

Comment: `DB_PREFIX = 'pre_';` --- what is this?!

Comment: Well, it seems like i mixed OOP dnd procedural php in a strange manner :) It's supposed to be define( 'DB_PREFIX', 'pre_' ) of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the question is is there a common practice how normally programmers solve this problem.

- Create a dump
- Create some kind of template using that dump, with `pre_` replaced with `%db_prefix%`
- When you need to change prefix - replace prefix in the template and import it to mysql

Comment: It's too obvious. I meant sth more simple. More non-programmers friendly, when i can just give a simple instruction "open this file and change some settings there" without involving db dumps

Comment: @kos: dynamic queries never were something that you should ever use. I recommend you don't even try to find how to implement it in the way you want.

Comment: i'm not the only one who uses them. Most public hosters give just a limited amount of databases to create, so there is no other way. But i guess you're right, i was almost sure there were not much chances to solve it. Although not all public hosters give privileges to create routines and triggers either.

Comment: @kos: you **can** do that with `PREPARE ... FROM`, but this will decrease performance dramatically. So it is a solution, but the solution I insist you not to use ;-)